# Hidden Navbar still pushes down view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a:

```
contentView()
SignUpView()
SignInView()
```

The contentView calls the `SignInView()`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SignInView()
        }
    }
}
```

In my SignUpView() I have:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
       NavigationLink(destination: SignInView()) {
          Text("Sign in")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(Color("startColor"))
        }
   }.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

In my SigbInView I have:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    NavigationLink(destination: SignUpView()) {
       Text("Sign up")
       .fontWeight(.semibold)
       .foregroundColor(Color("startColor"))
     }.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Im using `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to hide the bar, but the `< back` still appears in the top left hand corner to take you back to the previous screen, Iv also tried adding the navbar `text = ""` and setting the property to `.inline`

Im trying to only use these navigationLinks on the SignInView and SignUpViews to navigate, i don't want the bar to appear or push the view down.

Comment: I suppose you use `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in wrong place, it works well. It should d be inside NavigationView.

Comment: @Asperi, just updated my question to show more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like another property can be set to true to hide the back button:

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

This worked for me.